# Set Default Value in DropDownList Yii PHP

Tags: php, yii, html.dropdownlistfor

I have an admin panel in yii where I can edit/update **subtopics** And **topics**.

And On that edit/update page of ***subtopics*** there is a **foreign key** value referencing to the **topics** table.

I have a dropdown, which I have filled with the names of **Topics** on behalf of **topic ids**, but the problem is that the dropdown should show me the correct selected value of **topic** in **dropdown**. Instead it is showing the **first value**.

`My Code`

```
<?php
/* SubtopicsController */
/* @var $model Subtopics */
/* @var $form CActiveForm */
?>

<div class="form">
    <?php
        $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
            'id' => 'subtopics-form',
            'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
            'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
        ));
    ?>
....
//Some Irrelevant Code
....

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model, 'name', array('rows' => 1, 'cols' => 50)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'name'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    // This is the subjected dropdown
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'topic_id'); ?>
    <?php
       echo $form->dropDownList($model, 'topic_id', Subtopics::model()->get_AllTopics(), array(
           'ajax' => array(
               'data' => array('topic_id' => 'js:this.value'),
       )));
    ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'topic_id'); ?>
</div>


<div class="row buttons">
    <?php ?>
    <?php
    echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save');
    ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

**`What it is showing`**

[image: <code>What it is showing</code>]

**`And this is the option I want to be selected`**

[image: And this is the option I want to be selected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need that ajax option for this job, You just need to load all topics at the start

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'topic_id', CHtml::listData(Topic::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name')); ?>
```

Last two parameters of CHTML::listData are column names in topic table, primary key and what you want to display. I assumed those are "id" and "name".

```
Topic::model()->findAll()
```

Of course this can be customized to suit your needs. I even like to put in a method

This will always bound value in drop down on update

Cheers

Comment: It is returning null. The array is null. I am using below code, as you suggested:
    
   `<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'topic_id', CHtml::listData(Subtopics::model()->get_AllTopics(), 'id', 'name')); ?>`

Comment: Oh yeah my bad! it should be `<?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'topic_id', CHtml::listData(Topic::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'));`...

Thanks Man